# A JSONArray text must begin with '[' at character 1

Tags: java, arrays, json, spring, maven

Below is a simple piece of JSON that I'm trying to create a JSONArray from in java.

`Json:`

`[{
   "id":"15973726",
   "versionNumber":"5",
   "referenceNumber":"123",
   "specialInstructions":"Testing"
 }]`

When I try to do `JSONArray rows = JSONArray.fromObject(body);` (body being the JSON), I keep getting `A JSONArray text must begin with '[' at character 1`, but clearly it does begin with a `[`.

This was working fine in my application up until a recent upgrade that required me to change my java version from `1.6` to `1.8` in my `pom.xml`. Other than that, no major changes have been made. So not sure why this isn't working anymore.

`Java:`

```
@SuppressWarnings(
        {"rawtypes", "unchecked"})
@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public
@ResponseBody
String save(@RequestBody String body, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    String errorMessage = "";
    try {
        System.out.println(body);
        JSONArray rows = JSONArray.fromObject(new JSONTokener(body));
        System.out.println(rows);

        return "success";
    } catch (Exception e) {
        errorMessage = e.getMessage();
    }
    return errorMessage;
}
```

`"body":`

```
%5B%7B%22id%22%3A%2215973726%22%2C%22
versionNumber%22%3A%225%22%2C%  
22%22%2C%22referenceNumber%22%3A%22%22%2C%22
specialInstructions%22%3A%22%22%7D%5D=
```

`POM.xml:`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>app</artifactId>
<name>myApp</name>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
<properties>
    <java-version>1.8</java-version>
    <org.springframework-version>3.1.0.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
    <org.springframework.roo-version>1.0.2.RELEASE</org.springframework.roo-version>
    <org.aspectj-version>1.6.9</org.aspectj-version>
    <org.slf4j-version>1.6.1</org.slf4j-version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Roo dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.roo</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.springframework.roo.annotations</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.roo-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- AspectJ -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.15</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- @Inject -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Servlet -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.7</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Oracle driver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>11.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JPA Persistence -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.springsource.javax.persistence</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Java transaction -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.springsource.javax.transaction</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Java annotation -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.springsource.javax.annotation</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.springsource.org.hibernate.ejb</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.springsource.org.hibernate.validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.springsource.org.hibernate.annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1.ga</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- GZip Filter -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
        <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Jackson JSON Mapper -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <warName>${artifactId}</warName>
                <webappDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.name}</webappDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java-version}</source>
                <target>${java-version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>install</id>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>sources</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-beta-2</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Any ideas what is wrong here?

Comment: Is what you pasted the content of `body`? Can you use `body.trim()`?

Comment: Can you show us the actual JAVA code where you are attempting to read the JSON object into the JSON Array?

Comment: You can also print out your body before calling this `fromObject(body)` to verify the content going in

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz Java code added

Comment: @cricket_007 Added `body.trim()`.

Comment: The text `%5B` starts with a percent sign, not an open bracket. **`% != [`**. You could run a URL decoder on that text, but you should ask yourself why it was URL encoded at all, since you're not sending it as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Comment: @Andreas I'm adding a leading `[` and `]` in the javascript prior to making the post call. So it leaves the front end with brackets but arrives in the back end without.

Comment: No, it arrives URL encoded in the back end. `%5B%7B` is the URL encoded form of `[{`.

Comment: Of course it's an issue. Does `[{` and `%5B%7B` look the same to you? No? Well, doesn't look the same to the JSON parser either. --- *FYI:* If you URL decode the `body` text you show, you get `[{"id":"15973726","versionNumber":"5","","referenceNumber":"","specialInstructions":""}]`, which is not the same as the JSON you showed in the beginning.

Comment: I actually just added the dummy values in the original JSON keys just for demo purposes (123 and Testing), but those key values were actually empty. What's weird to me is why I'm going to have to URL decode this now going forward whereas up until now I've never had to. Just stumped on what changed to cause that.